# Val cannot be reassigned although I have a var (kotlin)?

Tags: android, kotlin, var, kotlin-android-extensions

I made a var extension property to data class like this:

```
var Element.bitmap: Bitmap?
        get() = downloadImg(PLACE_HOLDER_URL) //Default
        set(value) = this.bitmap.let {
            it = value ?: return@let
        }
```

However, the compiler complaining "Val cannot be reassigned" when I try to reassign "it" to the new value in this line:

```
it = value ?: return@let
```

I couldn't really understand why this happens?? I have a "var" bitmap property not "val", So what is the problem? And more importantly what is solution or alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable inside the lambdas are immutable, the `it` there is a shallow copy of the variable `bitmap`.

You should be using the `field` to assign into the backing field (actual variable).

```kotlin
set(value) {
    value?.let { field = it }
}
```

The `let` function creates a shallow copy of the variable, so that if a visible mutable variable (var) is changed by another thread then it can be safely used without risking mutation.

*Example:*

```kotlin
class Test {
    var prop: Int? = 5
}

fun main() {
    val test = Test()
    thread {
        Thread.sleep(100)
        test.prop = null
    }
    if (test.prop != null) {
        Thread.sleep(300)  // pretend we did something
        println(test.prop)  // prints null even inside if check
    }
}
```

To tackle these situations, a shallow copy is used such as with `let` which passes a immutable shallow copy of these.

```kotlin
class Test {
    var prop: Int? = 5
}

fun main() {
    val test = Test()
    thread {
        Thread.sleep(100)
        test.prop = null
    }
    test.prop?.let {  // `it` is a shallow copy, changes won't be reflected
        Thread.sleep(300)  // pretend we did something
        println(it)  // prints 5
    }
}
```

**Conclusion: `it` is not the actual variable itself, so changes won't reflect to the actual variable even if you would have been able to assign something to `it`.**

**Edit:** Extension properties can't have backing field, extensions are literally getters and setters.

- One thing you can do is to make a Map with a unique identifier in which you can store the values, but that might not be able to be garbage collected
- Another thing you can do (which I recommend) is to use delegation

*Delegation Example:*

```kotlin
class ElementBitmapDelegate {
    private var value: Bitmap? = null
    
    operator fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): Bitmap {
        return value ?: downloadImg(PLACE_HOLDER_URL).also { setValue(thisRef, property, it) }
        // return value or if value is null return from downloadImg() and set it to value
    }

    operator fun setValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, v: Bitmap?) {
        v?.let { value = it }  // if v is not null then set value to v
    }
}


var Element.bitmap: Bitmap? by ElementBitmapDelegate()
```

Comment: great explanation!! Thanks. I know about "field" keyword  But when I try to make as you said, compiler complaining again "Unresolved reference: field". Do you know about this error?

Comment: also this error happens only with extension properties when I try to make a normal var property not extension, it works fine. the compiler no more complaining about field keyword

Comment: Thanks a lot!!, solved my problem and saved my time

Answer (score 0):

In order to create a custom setter, you need to access to the backing field of the [property](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html) through `field` and not `it`, like this:

```
set(value) =  {
            field = value
        }
```

Comment: I tried it, the compiler says "Unresolved reference: field"

Comment: Oh I just noticed it was an extension property. Extension properties cannot have a backing field. You'll need to model it other way